# How to draw PieChart, Obtained Marks fill with some colour out of Total Marks without 3rd party library iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

**I want like this**

[image: output look like this]

*Any code example will be appreciated*

Comment: You may wish to look at the Charts library: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: you want it animated ?

Comment: yeah .. github.com/danielgindi/Charts you can look at this .. if you want to add dependency in your project ... or try to build it yourself .. its not that difficult umer ...

Comment: @jawadAli yes animated

Comment: @jawadAli i want to build by my self, don't want to depend some third party library

Comment: If you don't want to use a library, then check this custom Animated Circle Progress Bar
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3ltwjDJaMk

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on the web if you want to write this code yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting point ... created a circular progress view for your help

```
import UIKit
public class CircularProgressView: UIView {
  // First create two layer properties
  private lazy var circleLayer : CAShapeLayer = {
    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shape.lineCap = .round
    shape.lineWidth = 30.0
    shape.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7999292612, green: 0.8000453115, blue: 0.7999040484, alpha: 1)
    return shape

  }()

  private lazy var progressLayer : CAShapeLayer = {
    let progress = CAShapeLayer()
    progress.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
   // progress.lineCap = .round
       progress.lineWidth = 30.0
       progress.strokeEnd = 0
       progress.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.07347138971, green: 0.5590900779, blue: 0.8216868043, alpha: 1)
    return progress
  }()


  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    createCircularPath()
  }
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    createCircularPath()
  }


 private func createCircularPath() {

    updatePath()
    layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
    layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
  }
  public override func layoutSubviews() {
    updatePath()
  }

  private func updatePath() {
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2.0, y: frame.size.height / 2.0), radius: 80, startAngle: -.pi / 2, endAngle: 3 * .pi / 2, clockwise: true)

       circleLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
       progressLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
  }

}
public extension CircularProgressView {
  func progressAnimation(_ percentage:Float) {

    let circularProgressAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    circularProgressAnimation.duration = 1
    circularProgressAnimation.toValue = Float( percentage / 100 )
    circularProgressAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
    circularProgressAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    progressLayer.add(circularProgressAnimation, forKey: "progressAnim")
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want is something custom. This can be built custom or you can use a thridparty library with certain modifications. You a bunch of them on cocoapods but the one i would suggest is
https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts